# cross-correlation for list of data frames

Tags: r, for-loop

I have three data frames `Tushka`,`ARQE` and `ARQW`

I used cross-correlation code for every data frame separately like this

```
# cross correlations with US column

#Tushka

head(Tushka)

#  US    PW1    PW2    PW3    PW4

#1 173.62 153.01 144.65 152.53 137.05

#2 173.57 152.97 144.64 152.52 137.10

#3 173.52 152.95 144.64 152.52 137.11

lag = 200

t3 = data.frame(lag = c(-lag:lag))

vars = names(Tushka[, -1])

for (j in vars) {

 t4 = ccf(Tushka[, 1], Tushka[, j], lag = lag, na.action = na.pass)

 t3[, j] = data.frame(t4$acf)[, 1]

}
```

But if I create a list of the three data frame, how I can use cross-correlation for the list of data frames using for-loop or any other function

Answer (score 0):

Here is some reproducible sample data:

```
n <- 100
data_list <- list(
  d1 = data.frame(x = runif(n)),
  d2 = data.frame(x = runif(n)),
  d3 = data.frame(x = runif(n))
)
```

The trick is to use [`expand.grid`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.1/topics/expand.grid) to get pairs of data frames.

```
pairs <- expand.grid(first = names(data_list), second = names(data_list))
```

Now you can loops over rows of `pairs`, running cross correlation for each pair of data frames named in that row.

```
lapply(
  seq_len(nrow(pairs)),
  function(i)
  {
    first_data <- data_list[[pairs[i, "first"]]]
    second_data <- data_list[[pairs[i, "second"]]]
    ccf(first_data$x, second_data$x, plot = FALSE)
  }
)
```

Comment: I could not understand what did you do Richie

Comment: If you write a better question, you'll get a better answer.  What specifically don't you understand?  What have you tried?

Comment: @RichieCotton IF you did plot this and wanted to label the multi panel figure how would you do this? It's exactly what I'm trying to do.